# how to get value of one field to another field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I tried for below isssue but no luck.

i have contact object and **default description field in contact object.**
now i created another **description1 textarea field in contact object.**

i want to get automatically everytime contents of description field in description1 field.
Please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a Formula Look-up from the description1 textarea field to the description field in the contact object. You can probably do this easiest using workflow where the value is set when a record is created and every time it's updated.

Here are two references that may be of use in figuring out how to do this. The first is [Useful Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulWorkflowRules.meta/usefulWorkflowRules/workflow_examples.htm), the other is [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_preface.htm).